# Make HTML email signature responsive

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, inline

I'm just learning to create a responsive email signature. I am not good at coding so would appreciate any advice.

In part of the code shown below, do I need any special attributes to correct or make sure it's responsive?

I am editing in DreamWeaver and in Chrome preview it seems to work. Though, I have two columns and it's flexible only for the column text on the right, but it doesn't move the second column below the first column.

Also, how do I define which height or min-height to set for the table?

Sorry - I am really a newbie.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Email Signature</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">
<table style="width: 100%; min-height: 120px; font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td width="120" style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; border-right: 1px solid; border-right-color: #ba1f31; width: 120px; height: 100%; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: top; valign="top" rowspan="6">
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it still isn't reliably possible to use such features in an e-mail.  It might work for some clients, but others it will break on.  Even today, I'm still using table layouts and inlining all CSS and testing with Litmus.  Sadly, what you want to do may not be possible... at least not without conceding that it isn't going to work right for a large number of clients.

Comment: Just use an image. It will save you many hours of torture.

Comment: Sorry - I am confused. Most resources say HTML file is the proper way to create corporate email signatures...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible. Not for working on all mailing platforms (Outlook, gmail, apple mail, etc). Each one implements and standar of html, and many times is an old one.
You can use these guide to look for the best and most compatible elements: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-body/